# Mail sending failed using javamail : 550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

Tags: ssl, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am unable to setup my javamail session to send an email using my private mail service provider. I am using an auhenticated starttls session and am getting this error : `550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender`. Below is my mail session properties and debug trace :

```
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.host=smtp.myprovider.com
mail.smtp.password=*****
mail.smtp.port=587
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.smtp.user=****

javax.portlet.action[0] = sendMail
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.myprovider.com", port 587, isSSL false
220 smtp.myprovider.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 2 Jun 2015 11:35:22 -0400
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.myprovider.com", port: 587

EHLO sgmed001
250-smtp.myprovider.com Hello [xx.xx.xx.xx]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH NTLM
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250 CHUNKING
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "52428800"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "NTLM"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
EHLO sgmed001
250-smtp.myprovider.com Hello [xx.xx.xx.xx]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-AUTH NTLM LOGIN
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250 CHUNKING
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "52428800"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "NTLM LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
****
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
***
235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<sender@xx.xx>
250 2.1.0 Sender OK
RCPT TO:<recipient@xx.xx>
250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   recipient@xx.xx
DATA
354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
Date: Tue, 2 Jun 2015 11:35:23 -0400 (EDT)
From: sender@xx.xx
To: recipient@xx.xx
Message-ID: <53119439.11433259323689.JavaMail>
Subject: Request
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-Auto-Response-Suppress: AutoReply, DR, NDR, NRN, OOF, RN

qweqwe
.
550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1388)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.finishData(SMTPTransport.java:1215)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:586)
    at com.liferay.util.mail.MailEngine._send(MailEngine.java:563)
    at com.liferay.util.mail.MailEngine.send(MailEngine.java:350)
    at com.liferay.util.mail.MailEngine.send(MailEngine.java:425)
    at com.liferay.mail.messaging.MailMessageListener.doMailMessage(MailMessageListener.java:93)
    at com.liferay.mail.messaging.MailMessageListener.doReceive(MailMessageListener.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.BaseMessageListener.receive(BaseMessageListener.java:26)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.InvokerMessageListener.receive(InvokerMessageListener.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.ParallelDestination$1.run(ParallelDestination.java:69)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:682)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:593)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
11:35:23,696 ERROR [liferay/mail-1][MailEngine:77] null
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender_ [Sanitized]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1388)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.finishData(SMTPTransport.java:1215)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:586)
    at com.liferay.util.mail.MailEngine._send(MailEngine.java:563)
    at com.liferay.util.mail.MailEngine.send(MailEngine.java:350)
    at com.liferay.util.mail.MailEngine.send(MailEngine.java:425)
    at com.liferay.mail.messaging.MailMessageListener.doMailMessage(MailMessageListener.java:93)
    at com.liferay.mail.messaging.MailMessageListener.doReceive(MailMessageListener.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.BaseMessageListener.receive(BaseMessageListener.java:26)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.InvokerMessageListener.receive(InvokerMessageListener.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.ParallelDestination$1.run(ParallelDestination.java:69)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:682)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:593)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: This might help: https://support.desk.com/customer/portal/articles/1104707-client-does-not-have-permissions-to-send-as-this-sender-error

Comment: Thank for the quick reply and for the nice piece of useful info! So my problem was that the sender was outside the company. I changed it to one inside the company domain and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks to Steffen I was able to work it out, see comment above. In short the real problem was that I tried to send a mail using a sender outside my mail provider space. Using a mail address inside my provider's space made the email go and be sent away.